# How to extract elements from NLP Tree?

Tags: r, nlp, opennlp

I am using the **NLP** package to parse sentences.  How can I extract an element from the `Tree` output that is created?  For example I'd like to grab the Noun Phrases (`NP`) from the example below:

```
library(NLP)
library(openNLP)

s <- c(
    "Really, I like chocolate because it is good.", 
    "Robots are rather evil and most are devoid of decency"
)
s <- as.String(s)


sent_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
a2 <- annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))

parse_annotator <- Parse_Annotator()

p <- parse_annotator(s, a2)
ptexts <- sapply(p$features, `[[`, "parse")
ptexts

ptrees <- lapply(ptexts, Tree_parse)

ptrees

## [[1]]
## (TOP
##   (S
##     (S
##       (S
##         (ADVP (RB Really))
##         (, ,)
##         (NP (PRP I))
##         (VP
##           (VBP like)
##           (NP (NN chocolate))
##           (SBAR (IN because) (S (NP (PRP it)) (VP (VBZ is) (ADJP (JJ good)))))))
##       (. .)
##       (, ,)
##       (NP (NNP Robots))
##       (VP (VBP are) (ADJP (RB rather) (JJ evil))))
##     (CC and)
##     (S (NP (RBS most)) (VP (VBP are) (ADJP (JJ devoid) (PP (IN of) (NP (NN decency))))))))
```

I'd like to grab pieces from the `Tree` but can't figure out from the documentation for `Tree_parse`.  Using `str` indicates it should be easy to do but I can't achieve it.

I'd like it to return something like:

```
[1] "I"      "Robots"
```

Or as a `list` rather  than a vector.

This likely requires having **openNLPmodels.en** installed from: http://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/

Download and run

```
install.packages(
    "http://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/openNLPmodels.en_1.5-1.tar.gz",  
    repos=NULL, 
    type="source"
)
              `
```

If it's helpful folks can source the `Tree` directly in using the **curl** package from my Dropbox:

```
library(curl)
ptrees <- source(curl("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61803503/Errors/tree.R"))[[1]]
```