# recursively extract elements from a list of lists

Tags: r, list

I have the following type of nested list:

**What I have**

```
mylist <- list(
    "A",
    list(
        "B1",
        list(
            "C_B1",
            "w"
        ),
        "B2",
        list(
            "C_B2",
            "x"
        ),
        "B3",
        list(
            "C_B3_1",
            list(
                "D_B3_1",
                "y"
            ),
            "C_B3_2",
            list(
                 "D_B3_2",
                 "z"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Here the names of the list are actually stored as a pattern that seems to be a name followed by a list or single element.  This pattern can expand any number of times and within each list the pattern can repeat.

This data comes from a Tree structure from the **NLP** package.  Here is an example of this structure: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61803503/Errors/sample.R

**Desired Output**

```
list(
    A = list(
        B1 = list(
            C_B1 = "w"
        ),
        B2 = list(
            C_B2 = "x"
        ),
        B3 = list(
            C_B3_1 = list(
                D_B3_1 = "y"
            ),
            C_B3_2 = list(
                 D_B3_2 = "z"
            )
        )
    )
)

## $A
## $A$B1
## $A$B1$C_B1
## [1] "w"
## 
## 
## $A$B2
## $A$B2$C_B2
## [1] "x"
## 
## 
## $A$B3
## $A$B3$C_B3_1
## $A$B3$C_B3_1$D_B3_1
## [1] "y"
## 
## 
## $A$B3$C_B3_2
## $A$B3$C_B3_2$D_B3_2
## [1] "z"
```

***Note*** *that the degree of nesting is not guaranteed, just that there's a list of lists and the first element of each list is the name for the value (the second element) in the list.*

Comment: Your intent is unclear.  Do you need something more than just recursing on `names(current_list_element)` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I tried to show what I'm after with the desired output but I'm not sure how to explain it beyond this.  I don't think `names` is of help because the names are actually stored as the first element in the list and each nested sublist.

Comment: How did you get data in this structure in the first place?

Comment: Hmmmm... what you've listed after your double-sharps ( :-) ) is not clear.   How do you know when you've drilled down to the actual data (x,y,z in your example)?   If you can explain that, then some hacking with either `assign` or the infamous  `eval(parse(paste0(names(df[[1]])[1],'<- ', df[[1]][[1]][1]))` setup might do it.

Comment: @Dason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133394/extract-elements-from-nlp-tree?noredirect=1#comment44639944_28133394  It's a Tree from the **NLP** package.

Comment: Are the names always the first element or is it just that the lists always follow the pattern name1, data1, name2, data2, ... ?

Comment: @Dason the second one.  I see I was not accurate in my description.  I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm relying on the problem statement "Here the names of the list are actually stored as the first element in each list." and using a corrected example which follows this rule.

```
mylist <- 
list( "A",
    list("B1",
        list("C_B1",
            "w"),
        list("B2",
            list( "C_B2",
                "x")),
        list("B3",
            list( "C_B3_1",
                list( "D_B3_1",
                    "y"),
                list("C_B3_2",
                    list("D_B3_2",
                        "z")
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

One way to recursively iterate through a list of lists is to write a recursive function like so:

```
firstEltAsName  <-  function(x){
    # if x is not a list, return x
    if(!inherits(x,'list'))
        return(x)
    # recurse on everythin but the first element
    out  <-  lapply(x[-1],firstEltAsName)
    # take the names from the first element of the remaining elements.
    names(out)  <-  sapply(x[-1],`[`,1)
    # use the first element as the name 
    return(out)
}
firstEltAsName( mylist)
```

If your example is in fact correct, then you want:

```
OddEltsAsNames  <-  function(x){
    stopifnot(length(x)%%2 == 0)

    # recurse on the even elements
    out  <-  lapply(x[which(seq_along(x)%%2 == 0)],firstEltAsName)

    # take the names from the even elements 
    names(out)  <-  unlist( x[which(seq_along(x)%%2 == 1)] )

    return(out)
}
OddEltsAsNames( mylist)
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. Note that it's not always a two element list. It has the pattern list(name1, out1, name2, out2, name3, out3)

Comment: The OP states that "Here the names of the list are actually stored as the first element in each list." and I relied on an example (provided above) that actually fits this statement.

Comment: Yeah his example data and what he says in the problem don't perfectly match up.

Comment: @Dason if you could make it clearer an edit would be appreciated.

Comment: In your example, the first nested list has 6 elements; the odd elements are names and the even elements are lists.  This does not match the statement "Here the names of the list are actually stored as the first element in each list." because the names "B1", "B2", and "B3" do not fit this schema.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit ugly but works:

```
library(magrittr)

stackUp = function(lst)
{
    cond = lst %>% sapply(is.list) %>% any

    if(!cond) return(setNames(list(lst[[2]]), lst[[1]]))

    index = seq(1, length(lst), 2)

    index %>%
        lapply(function(u) stackUp(lst[[u+1]]))  %>%
        setNames(sapply(index, function(u) lst[[u]]))
}

> stackUp(mylist)
#$A
#$A$B1
#$A$B1$C_B1
#[1] "w"


#$A$B2
#$A$B2$C_B2
#[1] "x"


#$A$B3
#$A$B3$C_B3_1
#$A$B3$C_B3_1$D_B3_1
#[1] "y"


#$A$B3$C_B3_2
#$A$B3$C_B3_2$D_B3_2
#[1] "z"
```